# Deserializing JSON throws TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, json

My data json format is:

```
[{"Email":"apatil.558@gmail.com","EmpCode":"10004","MobileNo":"","Name":"Sample Manager Eternus User","Pan":"MMMMM9876M","Photo":null,"message":{"Message":"Success"}}]
```

So I wrote this class to deserialize it to:

```
public class EmpDetails
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pan { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to read it using this code:

```
private void SihnIn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     string uri = "http://xyz.d.in/service1.svc/getUser/MMMMM9876M/10004";
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
     webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
     webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
}

 void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
     var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpDetails>(e.Result); //Getting Error in this line
     string getEmail = jsonData.Email;
  }
```

Yet `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpDetails>(e.Result)` throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

How can I deserialize this JSON?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov There is no inner exception

Answer (score 2):

In the JSON string, the field "message" is not a string, it is an object.
You must change the definition of EmpDetails to the following to get it work :

```
public class EmpDetails
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pan { get; set; }
    public object Photo { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What did you try ? What is the exception you got and where ?

Comment: I got Exception on This line
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpDetails>(e.Result);

Comment: What is the value of e.Result ?

Comment: @ Cubi The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Comment: So you need to fix/handle this error before trying to deserialize any result. If the resultis not a valid JSON string, it will throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

may be you have wrong class, it should be:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class EmpDetails//changed name
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pan { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }//changed type
    public Message message { get; set; }
}
```

http://json2csharp.com/